# Deployment netlify white page

Tags: vite

I connected my website with gh-pages and now I want to deploy it on Netlify but there is only white page.

website inspect errors:

dex-e4c1c024.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

index-a25537c4.css:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

index-a25537c4.css:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Website build using: vitejs

My repo: `https://github.com/gines18/new`

`https://glittery-concha-26bcb7.netlify.app`

I've tried looking for help, google, vite, netlify website and still it's not working.